# Find a centroid of a dataset

Tags: c++, math, dataset, cluster-analysis, centroid

If I have some random data set let's say

```
X       Y
1.2     16
5.7     0.256
128.54  6.879
0       2.87
6.78    0
2.98    3.7
...     ...
 x'      y'
```

How can I find the centroid coordinates of this data set?

p.s. Here what I tried but got wrong results

```
float Dim1[K];
float Dim2[K];
float centroidD1[K];
float centroidD2[K];

int K = 4;
int counter[K];
for(int i = 0; i < K ; i++)
{
    Dim1[i] = 0;
    Dim2[i] = 0;
    counter[i] = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < hash["Cluster"].size(); j++)
    {
        if(hash["Cluster"].value(j) == i+1)
        {
            Dim1[i] += hash["Dim_1"].value(j);
            Dim2[i] += hash["Dim_2"].value(j);
            counter[i]++;
        }
    }
}

for(int l = 0; l < K; l++)
{
    centroidD1[l] = Dim1[l] / counter[l];
    centroidD2[l] = Dim2[l] / counter[l];
}
```

I guess I choose wrong algorithm for doing it, as I get wrong results.

Comment: Add all the numbers and divide by the number of elements?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Please see the updated post

Comment: What does your program output and what is the expected result?

Comment: Using the output I create new clusters, but the results are approximate.

Comment: Why in the world would the centroid be an array of values?  Isn't it just one X and one Y? (or D1 and D2)

Comment: Why are all your variables stored in this hash thing?  It looks like this does one update-step of a k-means clustering algorithm.  But there are other parts of the algorithm, like initialization and assignment.  Is this the only part that doesn't work right?

Comment: I have 15 dimensions, but it does not matter. If i get the result for 2 of them I will do it for all.

Comment: @Mike, 15 dimensions. How many rows?

Comment: Define: **wrong results**? Numerically wrong? Overflow? What does `hash` do? Doesn't look to me as if a hash function  makes sense here. How big is your data set? You may have numerical issues, consider using Kahan summation algorithm, maybe with additional weighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating a sum and dividing by N is not a good idea if you have a large data set. As your floating point accumulator grows adding a new point eventually stop working due to the magnitude difference. An incremental formula might work better, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing

If the issue is too large a data set you can verify the basic functioning of your code by using a smaller data set with a hand verified result. For example, just 1 data point, or 10 data points.